# GoogleApiClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, android

This is the code I have for trying to instantiate it:

```
private synchronized void callConnection(){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient().Builder
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

This is what I have in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

I get this error:

```
Error:(222, 28) error: GoogleApiClient is abstract; cannot be instantiated
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
 >Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: GoogleApiClient is abstract, you cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Answer (score 5):

It's a builder pattern so you need to instantiate `Builder` ( static inner class) object which is responsible to construct the underlying object with the defined operations (invoked methods) so use

```
new GoogleApiClient.Builder()
```

instead of

```
new GoogleApiClient().Builder
```